# Evaluating the integral $\int \frac{x^2+x}{(e^x+x+1)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals, closed-form

> Evaluate $$\int \frac{x^2+x}{(e^x+x+1)^2}dx$$

I tried converting in the form of Quotient rule(seeing the square in the denominator), neither am I able to make the denominators' derivative in the numerator. Some hints would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try partial fractions

Comment: @ArchisWelankar    Could you please elaborate? How do I apply partial fractions?

Comment: but the denominator is not a rational function

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One may observe that
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{x+1}{e^x+x+1}\right)'&=\frac{1 \times(e^x+x+1)-(x+1)(e^x+1)}{(e^x+x+1)^2}
\\\\&=\frac{(e^x+x+1)-(x+1)(e^x+x+1)+x(x+1)}{(e^x+x+1)^2}
\\\\&=\frac{-x(e^x+x+1)}{(e^x+x+1)^2}+\frac{x^2+x}{(e^x+x+1)^2}
\\\\&=\frac{\left((e^x+x+1)'-(e^x+x+1)\right)(e^x+x+1)}{(e^x+x+1)^2}+\frac{x^2+x}{(e^x+x+1)^2}
\\\\&=\frac{(e^x+x+1)'}{(e^x+x+1)}-1+\frac{x^2+x}{(e^x+x+1)^2}
\end{align}
$$ giving

> $$
> \int \frac{x^2+x}{(e^x+x+1)^2}dx=x-\ln\left|e^x+x+1\right|+\frac{x+1}{e^x+x+1}+C
> $$

for any constant $C$.

Comment: Have you checked this answer by differentiating? I couldn't seem to get it to match up.

Comment: @user5713492 Yes, by differentiaing the answer, you find the initial integrand.

Comment: Nice approach. +1

Comment: @OlivierOloa      Wait. How did you get from your last step to answer? The first fraction should be broken into the two terms both of which have to be integrated but where is the integration of the term $\frac{-1}{(e^x+x+1)}$? Or to sum up, how did you get the $x$ term in the answer?

Comment: Typo fixed. Please have a look. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, Wolfram|Alpha seems to agree with you. I guess I must not be calculating the derivative carefully enough. I might also have been thrown off by that typo.

Comment: How did you know to differentiate $\frac{x+1}{e^x+x+1}$?

Comment: @Math1000 By seeing an integrand of the form $\displaystyle \frac{\text{something}}{\left( e^x+x+1\right)^2}.$ I gave it a try.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\displaystyle u=\frac{x^2+x}{xe^x}=(x+1)e^{-x}$ and $\displaystyle dv=\frac{xe^x}{(e^x+x+1)^2}dx,\;$ so $\displaystyle du=-xe^{-x}dx$ and $\displaystyle v=\frac{e^x}{e^x+x+1}$.

Then $\displaystyle\int\frac{x^2+x}{(e^x+x+1)^2}dx=(x+1)e^{-x}\cdot\frac{e^x}{e^x+x+1}-\int-\frac{x}{e^x+x+1}dx=\frac{x+1}{e^x+x+1}+\int\frac{x}{e^x+x+1}dx$

$\displaystyle\hspace{.2 in}=\frac{x+1}{e^x+x+1}+\int\frac{e^x+x+1}{e^x+x+1}dx-\int\frac{e^x+1}{e^x+x+1}dx=\frac{x+1}{e^x+x+1}+x-\ln\big|e^x+x+1\big|+C$