# Looking for better approaches to evaluate $\int \dfrac{x^2+x}{(e^x+x+1)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int \dfrac{x^2+x}{(e^x+x+1)^2}dx$$

My multiple attempts are as follows:-

**Attempt $1$:**

Let's differentiate $\dfrac{f(x)}{e^x+x+1}$

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{f(x)}{e^x+x+1}\right)=\left(\dfrac{f'(x)(e^x+x+1)-f(x)(e^x+1)}{(e^x+x+1)^2}\right)$$

If we can choose $f(x)$ such that $f'(x)(e^x+x+1)-f(x)(e^x+1)$ equals to $x^2+x$, then our job will be done.

But I was not finding such $f(x)$.

**Attempt $2$**:

$$N_r=A(e^x+x+1)^2+2B(e^x+x+1)(e^x+1)$$
$$N_r=A(e^{2x}+x^2+1+2x+2xe^x+2e^x)+2B(e^{2x}+e^x+xe^x+x+e^x+1)$$
$$x^2+x=(A+2B)e^{2x}+(2A+4B)e^x+(2A+2B)xe^x+Ax^2+(2A+2B)x+A+2B$$

$$A+2B=0$$
$$A=1$$
$$2A+2B=0$$
$$2A+2B=1$$

So we don't have any solution for $A$ and $B$

**Attempt $3$:**

$$\int \dfrac{x^2+x+xe^x}{(e^x+x+1)^2}-\dfrac{xe^x}{(e^x+x+1)^2}dx$$
$$\int \left(\dfrac{(e^x+x+1)^2}{(e^x+x+1)^2}-\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{2(e^x+x+1)(e^x+1)}{(e^x+x+1)^2}\right)dx-\int \dfrac{xe^x}{(e^x+x+1)^2}dx$$

$$x-\ln(e^x+x+1)-\int \dfrac{xe^x}{(e^x+x+1)^2}dx$$

$$x-\ln(e^x+x+1)-\int \dfrac{(x+e^x+1-e^x-1)e^x}{(e^x+x+1)^2}dx$$

$$x-\ln(e^x+x+1)-\int \left(\dfrac{1}{e^x+x+1}-\dfrac{e^x+1}{(e^x+x+1)^2}\right)e^xdx$$

So we have the standard integral form $\int e^x\left(f(x)+f'(x)\right)=e^xf(x)+C$

$$x-\ln(e^x+x+1)-\dfrac{e^x}{e^x+x+1}+C$$

But it took me a lot of time to arrive at this. Is there any simple thing which I am missing here? Feel free to suggest your alternatives.

Comment: Are you sure your answer from attempt 3 is correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluating the integral $\int \frac{x^2+x}{(e^x+x+1)^2}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1778382/evaluating-the-integral-int-fracx2xexx12dx)

Comment: yeah I differentiated the answer and I got the integrand.

Comment: See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=int+%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E2%2Bx%7D%7B%28e%5Ex%2Bx%2B1%29%5E2%7Ddx

Comment: @Zacky, approaches mentioned here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1778382/evaluating-the-integral-int-fracx2xexx12dx are not good, I am searching for better approach. In all approaches, one is always trying to guess the integral instead of finding it by sophisticated methods, even my approach is better than those approaches, so I think this question needs more attention.

Comment: This answer is perfectly valid: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1778466/38584

Comment: @Zacky, I have edited the title, can you reopen the question?

Comment: this is the same I did, see my attempt 3

Comment: I fail to see what, specifically, is disliked about the proposed duplicates. There are several answers linked above which do not start with an answer and differentiate. Also note that questions such as "are there easier ways" are subjective. Realizing a part of the integrand is the derivative of something else and then using that is often times the easiest way about it.